# state_active="true" not working on drawable item

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

The `background` attribute of my `Spinner` points to a drawable file with 2 items: 1 with `android:state_active="true"` and 1 with `android:state_active="false"` - to have a different color when the user's finger is pressed down on the `Spinner`.

**spinner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_active="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:width="140dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
                    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:width="15dp" android:height="15dp" android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:right="10dp">
                <bitmap
                    android:src="@drawable/dropdown_triangle"
                    android:tint="@color/colorGreen" />
            </item>

        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_active="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:width="140dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#262626"/>
                    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:width="15dp" android:height="15dp" android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:right="10dp">
                <bitmap
                    android:src="@drawable/dropdown_triangle"
                    android:tint="@color/colorGreen" />
            </item>

        </layer-list>
    </item>
    </selector>
```

**activity xml**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/choose_user"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:shadowColor="@color/colorGreen"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

However, the `state_active="true"` item doesn't execute. When the `Spinner` is pressed, it doesn't change color.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for the spinner drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_default"></item>
</selector>
```